# TButton undeclared Identifier

Tags: delphi, button, vcl, undeclared-identifier

The following code is self created by Delphi which throws an error:

> undeclared identifier TButton

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

end.
```

Since it uses all the units required why does it throw an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TButton` is defined in `Vcl.StdCtrls` which is missing from the list of used units. Usually the IDE would add that missing unit to the list when you save the project.

Comment: That missing unit would also be added on compiling of the project. And sometimes Error Insight might still be reporting that same error even after adding all necessary units and compiling of your project. At least id did in previous versions of Delphi. And that is/was one of the know bugs of Error Insight